# Determining whether a node from a specific community appear more frequently than by random chance

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, graph-theory

Suppose I have a complete graph of 278 nodes with weighted edges (38503 unique edges), and 58/278 nodes belong to a specific community (i.e. subnetwork) of nodes, which we'll call "Community A". Suppose the edges are weighted by their association with some response variable of interest, and I hypothesize that Community A is particularly associated with this response variable.

Now suppose I performed a feature selection step (irrelevant here) and determined that 32/38503 edges are significantly associated with this response variable. Of those 32 edges, 17 of those edges contain exactly one node that belongs to Community A.

**Question:** I'm interested in determining whether edges involving one Community A node are selected as features at a significantly higher proportion than what we'd expect by chance alone, assuming edges are randomly sampled.

Thanks in advance; I'm rusty with my combinatorics and selecting the right statistical test here is a challenge as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 58 nodes in community A, so there are 278-58 nodes not in community A. The number of edges with exactly 1 node from community A is then 58(220)=12760. The unbiased probability that edge containing exactly 1 community A node is then 12760/38503.

WE obseved 17/32 edges from community A. To compare the two proportions, do a one-sample z-test of proportions.

In R, it is the following,

```
> prop.test(17, 32, 12760/38503)

    1-sample proportions test with continuity correction

data:  17 out of 32, null probability 12760/38503
X-squared = 4.9013, df = 1, p-value = 0.02684
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.3314027
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3503305 0.7048986
sample estimates:
      p 
0.53125
```

The conclusion indicates that the proportion is different from the null probability.